# mysql: how to change column to be PK Auto_Increment

Tags: sql, mysql

is there a single select statement that will do all three of those: primary key, unique, and auto_increment?

Comment: Do you mean a single ALTER statement? You don't actually use SELECT statements to alter table structures.

Comment: when you completely invert the sense of the question after you get answers, it makes those answers look really stupid.  If you now are asking for the opposite of what you originally asked for, I think you should ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we create a little table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test2 (id int);
```

Note Null is YES, and `id` is not a primary key, nor does it auto_increment.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE test2;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the alter command:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE test2 MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL auto_increment, ADD primary key (id);
```

Now Null is NO, and `id` is a primary key with auto_increment.

```
mysql> describe test2;
describe test2;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Primary keys are always unique.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key is always unique.

Comment: you should be aware the the question was completely inverted after you left your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter the database structure with [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) (data manipulation language) statements like `SELECT`. You need [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) (data definition language) statements. Table columns can be modified with `ALTER TABLE`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

The syntax is basically this:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`
CHANGE COLUMN `bar` `bar` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`foo`);
```

As about the exact changes you want to do, you must know that in relational databases a primary key is a value that serves to uniquely identify each row in a table. It won't serve such purpose if it's not unique or NULL.